# Two API calls, second call needs information from the first

Tags: node.js, axios, nested, openweathermap

trying to use information from an API call to then send a second call.

Here's what I've got:

This is the first API call, I've got it working and rendering; it gathers information for disc golf courses.

```
async function dgcrGetReq(res, cityName) {
    var courseData = {
        title: "courses",
        courses: null
    };
    await axios.get(`${dgcrUrl}?key=${dgcrKey}&mode=findloc&city=${cityName}&state=ON&country=CA&sig=${torontoSig}`)
    .then(function (response){
        //Run the weather API call
        courseData.courses = response.data;
        res.render("courses", courseData);
    }).catch(function (error){
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Here's the second API call:
It collects weather data using latitude and longitude

```
async function getWeather(res) {
    var weatherData = {
        title: "Weather Information",
        weather: null
    };
    await axios.get(`${weatherUrl}${weatherKey}`)
    .then(function (response){
        weatherData.weather = response.data;
        res.render("weather", weatherData);
    }).catch(function (error){
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

What I need is to collect the latitude and longitude elements from the disc golf API and use them as parameters for the Weather app.  I know I need to squeeze the second call into the first somehow but I'm unsure of where it actually belongs.  I'm using node.js and axios, looking for solutions that don't stray from those technologies.

Links:
[DGCR API documentation](https://www.dgcoursereview.com/api_docs.php)
[Open Weather Map Documentation](https://openweathermap.org/current)

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956521/chain-requests-so-i-can-use-data-from-my-first-request-in-my-second-one?rq=1

Comment: This looks useful however I'm not using React, just plain Node.js so I'm looking for a solution that works with that constraint.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you want to call your `weather` API call from within `dgcrGetReq()`

First of all please don't mix promises `then/catch` syntax with `async/await`

You have to modify `getWeather` so that it accepts `lat/long` variables

```
async function getWeather(lat, long) {
    try {
        let weatherData = {
            title: "Weather Information",
            weather: null
        };

       //You can fix the URL accordingly
        await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid={/*Your API key*/}`);
        weatherData.weather = response.data;

        return weatherData;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }

}
```

Now Call `getWeather` in here

```
async function dgcrGetReq(res, cityName) {
    try {
        let courseData = {
            title: "courses",
            courses: null
        };
        const golfData = await axios.get(`${dgcrUrl}?key=${dgcrKey}&mode=findloc&city=${cityName}&state=ON&country=CA&sig=${torontoSig}`);

        courseData.courses = response.data;

        const weatherData = await getWeather(golfData.latitude, golfData.longitude);

        res.render("courses", courseData);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }

}
```

Not sure what are you trying to achieve with multiple `res.render()` but you might have to modify your code a bit in order to send all the data.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking the time to write this up - I'm going to give it a try