# How to break for loop when axios post succeeds?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to break for loop when `axios.post` succeeds. How can I do this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < filteredCars.length; i++) {
  var car = filteredCars[i];
  axios
    .post(
      "http://localhost:9000/api/cars/" + car.id + "/createReservation",
      {
        pick_up_date: "July 29, 2023 03:00:01",
        drop_off_date: "July 30, 2023 09:00:00"
      },
      config
    )
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        reserved: true
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: It is an `async` request inside a loop, which may not give you the correct results. Use a recursive function.

Comment: Do you want to issue a POST for all of the cars in your array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182951/axios-chaining-multiple-api-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `await` inside an async function. So your method will be as follows:

```
async function testFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < filteredCars.length; i++) {
        var car = filteredCars[i];
        var response = await axios.post("http://localhost:9000/api/cars/" + car.id + "/createReservation";
        this.setState({ reserved: true });

        if (conditionToBreak === true) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```